# How do I change the height of a Flexbox-Item?

Tags: css, flexbox, height

I try to set a height (100% of the parent-element) for a flex-item. It's a li-tag in the nav. I got a border-left on every li-tag but the border just doesn't fit the size of the container. Also it's well better to click anywhere in the area instead of, on the -Tag directly, So that I could make the a-tag of the navigation also to 100%.

I set a min-height and tried it with display: block, but that doesn't ruled it.

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

nav {
    background: #100e17;
}

.inline {
    display: inline;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.reset {    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navLogo {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

#logoText {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
    margin: 1rem;
    margin-left: 0.3rem;
}

#navLogoImg {
    height: auto;
    width: 2rem;
}

.menuItem {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin: 0rem 1.5rem; 
}

ul.flex li {
    border-left: 1px solid #201c29;
    min-height: 100%;
    }
```

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A Complete Guide to Grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="reset">
    <nav cla>
    <ul class="reset flex">
        <li class="inline"><a href="index.html" class="inline" id="navLogo">
            <img class="inline" id="navLogoImg" src="Bilder/CSSTricks_Rad.png">
            <h3 class="inline" id="logoText">CSS-TRICKS</h3>
            </a></li>  
        <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Almanac</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Snippets</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Newsletter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Guides</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```
````

Here's a little image of the border and nav in general (trying to recreate CSS-Tricks.com:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InKbg.png)

Comment: PS: The "align-items: center"-property cuts the height. Can I fix it somehow?

Comment: remove the `align-items: center;` and then center the text inside, not the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `align-items: stretch;` on flex to get them to 100% height. Remove `min-height: 100%;` on the li and then style the anchor to be 100% height, flexed and aligned center.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

nav {
  background: #100e17;
}


.flex {
  display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.reset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navLogo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

#logoText {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: white;
  margin: 1rem;
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
}

#navLogoImg {
  height: auto;
  width: 2rem;
}

.menuItem {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0rem 1.5rem;
}

ul.flex li {
  border-left: 1px solid #201c29;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>A Complete Guide to Grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="reset">
  <nav>
    <ul class="reset flex">
      <li>
        <a href="index.html" class="inline" id="navLogo">
          <img id="navLogoImg" src="Bilder/CSSTricks_Rad.png">
          <h3 id="logoText">CSS-TRICKS</h3>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Articles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Videos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Almanac</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Snippets</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Newsletter</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Jobs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menuItem">Guides</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```